# LAN not working in Ubuntu with Realtek

Tags: networking, drivers, internet, realtek

My internet on Ubuntu is not working, but on Windows it is.

I know that my drivers are Realtek.

**EDIT**

Re-installed Ubuntu.

Internet is working when I edit **/etc/resolv.conf**

from

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search home
```

to

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search home
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.8.4
```

How can I make my internet work permanently?

ifconfig -a:

```
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fc:aa:14:06:2e:84  
          inet addr:192.168.2.6  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::af5f:9d3e:709e:a2c8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:38 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:57 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4287 (4.2 KB)  TX bytes:7111 (7.1 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:201 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:201 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:14922 (14.9 KB)  TX bytes:14922 (14.9 KB)
```

sudo lshw -C network

```
[sudo] password for jarno: 
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 06
       serial: fc:aa:14:06:2e:84
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 ip=192.168.2.6 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:30 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7c00000-f7c00fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
```

lspci | grep Ethernet

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
```

Comment: There is no need to edit `/etc/resolv/conf` as it is written in the file. Why are you trying to setup `/etc/network/interfaces`? Is it a server?

Comment: No it is just my personal desktop, do you know how I can fix what I messed up and make my LAN connection working?

Comment: Remove everything you added to `/etc/network/interfaces` and configure network using Network Manager. If you do not get proper DNS, you can set it there.

Comment: Okay so I removed it, but it is still not working.

Comment: "Not working" gives no information. Does it get an IP address, can you ping the gateway, etc?

Comment: ifconfig -a shows only the details of my original post. So the 'lo' part with inet addr 127.0.0.1 and mask 255.0.0.0. Nothing else. I can ping to 127.0.0.1

Comment: @Pilot6 Re-installed Ubuntu, please see me edited post.

Comment: Set DNS in Network Manager as I said.

Comment: I'm not really into this stuff. How do I know my DNS?

Comment: You set `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.8.4` for some reason, but you are doing it at a wrong place.

Comment: I did that because someone said that in the comments on another post just to be able to download other stuff. I don't think it is the proper way because they are the name servers of Google.